# Should I use `gpio_free` before using `gpio_desc` which is returned by `gpio_to_desc`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, gpio

## Update at 2020/10/31

Thanks for [0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) [asking the question on mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-gpio/CACRpkdYjHERoO-rzoXa77VCjDrF0N+3q+q_MXOstMEkk3Y2CnA@mail.gmail.com/T/#t). And Alexandre Courbot aka [Gunurou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251248/gnurou) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610316/4123703) my question!

I have to thank [0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) again! Your are the true hero behind this question.

---

### Old Question:

This question seems like typo in documentation, but I want to double check.

My question is the last two paragraphs in the last section of [GPIO Descriptor Consumer Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/consumer.txt).

> the following two functions allow you to convert
> a GPIO descriptor into the GPIO integer namespace and vice-versa:
>
> ```
> int desc_to_gpio(const struct gpio_desc *desc)
> struct gpio_desc *gpio_to_desc(unsigned gpio)
> ```
>
> The GPIO number returned by desc_to_gpio() can be safely used as long
> as the GPIO descriptor has not been freed. All the same, a GPIO number
> passed to gpio_to_desc() must have been properly acquired, and usage
> of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible **after the GPIO number
> has been released.**
>
> Freeing a GPIO obtained by one API with the other API is forbidden and
> an unchecked error.

My understanding for each sentence

> The GPIO number returned by desc_to_gpio() can be safely used as long as the GPIO descriptor has not been freed.

Any GPIO pin could be use before `gpiod_put()` free the descriptor. Following is pseudo code for my understanding.

```c
struct gpio_desc desc = gpiod_get(...);
gpio pin = desc_to_gpio(desc);

// operation here

gpiod_put(desc);
```

---

> All the same, a GPIO number passed to gpio_to_desc() must have been properly acquired, and usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible after the GPIO number has been released.

I'm confused with `"All the same"` and `"usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible after the GPIO number has been released"`.

If `"All the same"` applies, I presume `gpio_desc` could be used before `gpio_free()`. But "usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible after the GPIO number has been released" makes me think I have to `gpio_free()` before using `gpio_desc` returned from `gpio_to_desc()`.

To re-state my question, which of the following code snippet should be correct usage of `gpio_to_desc()`?
I presume `"usage of the returned GPIO descriptor"` means the `gpio_desc` return from `gpio_to_desc()`.

I thought second one should be incorrect, but I'd like to be confirmed with any documentation or example for it.

1. Use `gpio_desc` before free.

```c
    gpio pin = gpio_request( ... );
    struct gpio_desc desc = gpio_to_desc(pin);
    
    // gpiod operation here, before free
    
    gpio_free(gpio_desc)
```

2. Using `gpio_desc` AFTER free.

```c
    gpio pin = gpio_request( ... );
    struct gpio_desc desc = gpio_to_desc(pin);
    gpio_free(gpio_desc)
    
    // gpiod operation here, after free
```

In other words, should

"usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible after the GPIO number has been released"

be changed to

"usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible ***before*** the GPIO number has been released"?

---

### Side question

According to this sentence.

> Freeing a GPIO obtained by one API with the other API is forbidden and an unchecked error.

Should I NOT release the `gpio_desc` with `gpiod_put()` returned by `gpio_to_desc()`?

---

### Keywords on Google.

- `gpio_to_desc()` must `gpio_free()` first

  No offical articles mention about it.
- `gpio_to_desc()` `gpiod_put()`

  I found [header files](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/gpio/consumer.h#L532). However it doesn't explain it.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy, let me delete my comments before they cause more confusion!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, Louis, to be on cnstructrive side I have dug into the Git history. So it was a ~1 year period of time when this chapter used to be correct. But world is changing... Some details in the thread: https://lore.kernel.org/linux-gpio/CACRpkdYjHERoO-rzoXa77VCjDrF0N+3q+q_MXOstMEkk3Y2CnA@mail.gmail.com/T/#t Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @0andriy oh you actually asked on the GPIO mailing list, nice! That makes more sense now. You should turn that into an answer :)

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for asking the question! Your work deserves an answer :)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, you got the answer by the author of that documentation :-)

Comment: @0andriy just saw that, amazing haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to this question is **don't ever call these functions**. They have been obsolete since 2014 and there should be no reason for new code to use them. New code should only rely on the `gpiod_*()` family of functions, and never work with GPIO numbers.

If you deal with old code, the safest thing to do is to convert it to use the gpiod interface first thing.

Now if you absolutely need to work with these functions, my recollection is that the following usages are valid (copied from your question):

```c
struct gpio_desc desc = gpiod_get(...);
gpio pin = desc_to_gpio(desc);

// operation here

gpiod_put(desc);
```

```c
gpio pin = gpio_request( ... );
struct gpio_desc desc = gpio_to_desc(pin);
   
// gpiod operation here, before free
  
gpio_free(gpio_desc)
```

That's because the `gpio_*()` family of functions are built on top of the gpiod interface, as you can see in *drivers/gpio/gpiolib-legacy.c*. So the descriptor corresponding to the GPIO number you requested will have been acquired by `gpiod_request()`, and thus is guaranteed to remain valid until `gpio_free()` (which really just calls `gpiod_free()` is invoked.

As for your side question:

> Should I NOT release the gpio_desc with gpiod_put() returned by gpio_to_desc()?

That's correct, you should never do that. At the moment the APIs are built in such a way that doing so *might* work, but there is no guarantee they will not diverge in the future. Also if you acquired a descriptor, there is no reason why you could not keep it around to free it using the correct API.

But again, the best thing to do is assume that these functions do not exist, and use gpiod everywhere you can.

Answer (score 0):

> > All the same, a GPIO number passed to gpio_to_desc() must have been properly acquired, and usage of the returned GPIO descriptor is only possible **after** the GPIO number has been released.
>
> Shouldn't **after** be changed to **before**?

Probably neither of them.  I guess that the sentence wants to express not to mix legacy `gpio_XXX` and modern `gpiod_XXX` APIs.  E.g. to release `gpio` resources before working with `gpiod` ones.

You are right, that using the descriptor after `gpio_free()` is wrong.

In practice, the kernel violates the stated sentence itself because nearly every `gpio` operation uses `gpio_to_desc()`.  E.g.

```c
void gpio_free(unsigned gpio)
{
    gpiod_free(gpio_to_desc(gpio));
}
```

or

```c
static inline void __gpio_set_value(unsigned gpio, int value)
{
    return gpiod_set_raw_value(gpio_to_desc(gpio), value);
}
```

Both `gpio_to_desc()` and `desc_to_gpio()` do **not** acquire resources but return pointers to existing objects:

```c
struct gpio_desc *gpio_to_desc(unsigned gpio)
{
  ...
            return &gdev->descs[gpio - gdev->base];
}
```

```c
int desc_to_gpio(const struct gpio_desc *desc)
{
    return desc->gdev->base + (desc - &desc->gdev->descs[0]);
}
```

Comment: I thought "usage of the returned GPIO descriptor" means the return `gpio_desc` from `gpio_to_desc` and "GPIO number has been released." means the argument of `gpio_to_desc`. After your explaination, I presume the latter sentence "Freeing..." should be taken into account when reading "All the same...".

Comment: @0andry: no; `gpio_free()` calls `gpiod_free()` which can render the information within the descriptor invalid (e.g. it does a `module_put(desc->gdev->owner)`)

Comment: I would argue that if the intended usage of the API is to first `free()` and then use the object, then it's completely insane. I would not expect Linus to approve something like this.